# Linphone Malloc error break

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, malloc, linphone

Working on a Linphone custom for myself, everything is mostly ok, but when i went to test the Pushkit and Voip push i got this error. 
Can anybody help me spot whats going on?
Im fairly new to XCode/swift/ObjectiveC, so its kinda hard to understand all this error msgs.

Btw i got all the certificates needed to uso PushKit.

```
Oct 14 11:12:31  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Changing [client] [REGISTER] transaction [0x61000035e560], from state [COMPLETED] to [TERMINATED]
Oct 14 11:12:31  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Client internal REGISTER transaction [0x61000035e560] terminated
Oct 14 11:12:31  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Changing [client] [REGISTER] transaction [0x610000541600], from state [COMPLETED] to [TERMINATED]
Oct 14 11:12:31  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Client internal REGISTER transaction [0x610000541600] terminated
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Background task belle-sip recv channel started. Unknown remaining time since application is not fully in background.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Warning>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000]: recv background task has to be ended now, but work isn't finished.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000]: starting recv background task with id=[12].
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000]: ending recv background task with id=[12].
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000]: received [973] new bytes from [UDP://fone.isuper.com.br:5060]:
    INVITE sip:280@177.8.248.2:63183;transport=udp SIP/2.0
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.8.248.10:5060;branch=z9hG4bK73bc6c39;rport
    Max-Forwards: 70
    From: "PD-Rodrigo" <sip:279@177.8.248.10>;tag=as5859feed
    To: <sip:280@177.8.248.2:63183;transport=udp>
    Contact: <sip:279@177.8.248.10:5060>
    Call-ID: 2b1b5cbc26ac66275f34701674365df2@177.8.248.10:5060
    CSeq: 102 INVITE
    User-Agent: PhoneBox PBX
    Date: Fri, 14 Oct 2016 14:12:35 GMT
    Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, REFER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, INFO, PUBLISH, MESSAGE
    Supported: replaces, timer
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Content-Length: 375

    v=0
    o=root 1941729179 1941729179 IN IP4 177.8.248.10
    s=Asterisk PBX 11.13.1
    c=IN IP4 177.8.248.10
    t=0 0
    m=audio 15694 RTP/AVP 0 8 3 97 18 101
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
    a=rtpmap:3 GSM/8000
    a=rtpmap:97 iLBC/8000
    a=fmtp:97 mode=30
    a=rtpmap:18 G729/8000
    a=fmtp:18 annexb=no
    a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
    a=fmtp:101 0-16
    a=ptime:20
    a=sendrecv
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000] [598] bytes parsed
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000] read [375] bytes of body from [fone.isuper.com.br:5060]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Changing [server] [INVITE] transaction [0x618000757c30], from state [INIT] to [PROCEEDING]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/channel [0x7fc5349a1000]: message sent to [UDP://fone.isuper.com.br:5060], size: [271] bytes
    SIP/2.0 100 Trying
    Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 177.8.248.10:5060;branch=z9hG4bK73bc6c39;rport
    From: "PD-Rodrigo" <sip:279@177.8.248.10>;tag=as5859feed
    To: <sip:280@177.8.248.2:63183;transport=udp>
    Call-ID: 2b1b5cbc26ac66275f34701674365df2@177.8.248.10:5060
    CSeq: 102 INVITE
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/New server dialog [0x6180001dc5c0] , local tag [yiWGtZ9], remote tag [as5859feed]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/op [0x7fc532d1f240] : set_or_update_dialog() current=[0x0] new=[0x6180001dc5c0]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/new incoming call from ["PD-Rodrigo" <sip:279@177.8.248.10>] to [<sip:280@177.8.248.2:63183;transport=udp>]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload PCMU/8000 fmtp=
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload PCMA/8000 fmtp=
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload GSM/8000 fmtp=
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload iLBC/8000 fmtp=mode=30
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload G729/8000 fmtp=annexb=no
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found payload telephone-event/8000 fmtp=0-16
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Searching for already_a_call_with_remote_address.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found media local-ip from signaling.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/New LinphoneCall [0x7fc533a22e00] initialized (LinphoneCore version: 3.10.2-293-g8958eaa)
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/audio stream index found: 0, updating main audio stream index
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/RtpSession bound to [0.0.0.0] ports [7246] [7247]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/rtp_session_enable_network_simulation:DISABLING NETWORK SIMULATION
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Configured srtp crypto suite: AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_80 
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Configured srtp crypto suite: AES_CM_128_HMAC_SHA1_32 
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Configured srtp crypto suite: AES_256_CM_HMAC_SHA1_80 
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Configured srtp crypto suite: AES_256_CM_HMAC_SHA1_32 
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Creating ZRTP engine on rtp session [0x7fc533945000] ssrc 0x3da7b9ea
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Setting DSCP to 46 for MSAudio stream.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Equalizer location: mic
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/cannot set noise gate mode to [0] because no volume send
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Cannot determine multicast role for stream type [video] on call [0x7fc533a22e00]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/RtpSession bound to [0.0.0.0] ports [9294] [9295]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/rtp_session_enable_network_simulation:DISABLING NETWORK SIMULATION
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Initializing multistream ZRTP context on rtp session [0x7fc5339e4c00] ssrc 0xcd914f27
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Setting DSCP to 0 for MSVideo stream.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Cannot determine multicast role for stream type [text] on call [0x7fc533a22e00]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/RtpSession bound to [0.0.0.0] ports [11078] [11079]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/rtp_session_enable_network_simulation:DISABLING NETWORK SIMULATION
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Created new ICE check list for stream [0]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Found media local-ip from signaling.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Don't put video stream on local offer for call [0x7fc533a22e00]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Don't put text stream on local offer for call [0x7fc533a22e00]
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/Doing SDP offer/answer process of type incoming
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/No match for GSM/8000/1
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/No match for iLBC/8000/1
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/No match for G729/8000/1
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: bel/Background task liblinphone call notification started. Unknown remaining time since application is not fully in background.
Oct 14 11:12:33  linphone[6403] <Notice>: lib/linphone_ringtoneplayer_ios_start_with_cb: using ringtone /Users/joelsene/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3ED2130C-2343-49A3-93CA-24776C42E4D8/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/AB8E7BC4-03A7-40EC-A3B6-7465E5E8DBD9/linphone.app/notes_of_the_optimistic.caf
linphone(6403,0x700000783000) malloc: *** error for object 0x60800020e720: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
(lldb)
```

Comment: The C library's memory management metadata has become corrupted.  This very likely arises from your code overrunning the bounds of an allocated object, but we cannot give you any specifics without examining the code.

Comment: Thankyou @JohnBollinger, but the code is huuge, is there any specific place i should look? or should i just start over? Because im only workin on a frontend custom job, shouldnt have messed with the code.

Comment: If you've modified code that you now think you should have left alone then reverting those changes is certainly a viable option.  If you want to troubleshoot this then a tool such as `valgrind` might help you locate the source of the problem.

Comment: Thanks again @JohnBollinger im going to start it over to see what i did wrong.